# Error pushing -meta.xml to scratch org: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, xml

I was attempting to use the SFDX CLI to push the following file to a scratch org:

force-app>main>default>messageChannels>**SettingCategory_Selected.messageChannel-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <masterLabel>SettingCategorySelected</masterLabel>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <description>Message Channel to pass a category</description>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>category</fieldName>
        <description>This is the Setup Category that changed</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

The push failed with the error:

> force-app\main\default\messageChannels\SettingCategory_Selected.messageChannel-meta.xml
> **Error parsing file: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. (2:6)**

Why is it failing to push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closer look at the XML file makes the problem apparent:

[image: XML file with empty lines before XML starts]

There is an empty line / blank space before the XML prolog. Clearing out everything before the `<xml version...` resolved the somewhat cryptic error message.